# Running JS code on web pages

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where I need to run some script(which downloads files). I want to run these scripts on web page and I don't have access to source code of those files. How can I make sure that my scripts are run as the page is done loading. Can this be done using chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

When you're in chrome press  ctrl+shif+J to bring up the console. run your code there

Comment: Problem with this approach is that it won't work when I want to run the same script on many pages and I am not typing it in console rather I want it to be done in some automated way

Comment: if you want to download a website, you can use a website downloader

Comment: Don't want to download whole website, I just want to run some scripts on web page opened in a browser window.